# Close sidenav when backdrop is clicked

Tags: angular, events, angular-material, ngrx

I am new to Angular Material, ngrx and modern Angular. Trying to implement a basic header layout with a toolbar that has a title and a menu icon and a sidenav to hold links. The sidenav should open when I click on the menu icon and it should close when I click on the area outside of the sidenav (backdrop). I am using the ngrx example app as a reference.

I have tried to emit an event when the user clicks on the sidenav container using (click) and (backdropClick).

app.component.ts

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import * as fromRoot from '@client-app/reducers';
import { LayoutActions } from '@client-app/core/actions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <app-layout (closeMenu)="closeSidenav()">
      <app-toolbar (openMenu)="openSidenav()">Memories</app-toolbar>
      <app-sidenav [open]="(showSidenav$ | async)!">

      </app-sidenav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </app-layout>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  showSidenav$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    this.showSidenav$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.selectShowSidenav);
  }
  closeSidenav() {
    this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.closeSidenav());
  }
  openSidenav() {
    this.store.dispatch(LayoutActions.openSidenav());
  }
}
```

layout.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  template: `
    <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
  `,
})
export class LayoutComponent {
  @Output() closeMenu = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

sidenav.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidenav',
  template: `
    <mat-sidenav
      position="end"
      [opened]="open"
    >
      <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item href="login">Login</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="signup">Signup</a>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      mat-sidenav {
        width: 200px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class SidenavComponent {
  @Input() open = false;
}
```

toolbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  template: `
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="openMenu.emit()" aria-label="menu">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      mat-toolbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class ToolbarComponent {
  @Output() openMenu = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`closeMenu` within `LayoutComponent` does never emit a value, thus the action is never dispatched, and the sidebar will not close.

The NgRx example app closes the menu within the `SidenavComponent` component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bc-sidenav',
  template: `
    <mat-sidenav
      #sidenav
      [opened]="open"4
      
      (keydown.escape)="sidenav.close()"
      
      (closedStart)="closeMenu.emit()"
      disableClose
    >
      <mat-nav-list>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      mat-sidenav {
        width: 300px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class SidenavComponent {
  @Input() open = false;
  @Output() closeMenu = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```